# Storing mouse co-ordinates in session and adding to xml string (C# .NET MVC)

Tags: c#, xml, session

basically my aim is to use JQuery to post back an x & y mouse co-ordinate to my controller where the 2 values are added to an array/list which is then added to the session.

I want to iterate through a series of 60 clicks (and subsequently postbacks to the controller) before building an XML string with each co-ordinate in it.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<xml>
<click1>
 <xpos>45</xpos>
 <ypos>55</ypos>
</click1>
<click2>
 <xpos>45</xpos>
 <ypos>55</ypos>
</click2>
</xml>
```

I'm unsure as to how best to store the individual mouse clicks after each postback, and I thought perhaps a session and a multi-dimensional array/list would be good for this?  I'm also a little confused as to how to convert the session back into a list and assemble the XML as required.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Sykth.

Comment: How would you store a date in session?  It should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a Dictionary of type , with MouseCoordinates referring to a class which accepted 2 string values for xposition and yposition.

I then placed the Dictionary into a session, re-casting it as a Dict when I needed to add a new value to it.

Finally I looped through the Dictionary at the end of my cycle of clicks retrieving all the values.

I hope this code helps someone:

```
var coords = new Dictionary<int, MouseCoordinates>();

HttpContext.Session.Add("coords", coords);

// Accessing Dictionary From Session
var coords = (Dictionary<int, MouseCoordinates>)HttpContext.Session["coords"];

// Adding Values using a integer stage that's posted back to the controller
coords.Add(currentStage, new MouseCoordinates { xposition = xpos, yposition = ypos });

// Looping through the session at the end of the cycle
            foreach (var ords in coords)
            {
                var qnode = ords.Key;
                var xvalue = ords.Value.xposition;
                var yvalue = ords.Value.yposition;
            }
```

Comment: +2 for coming back and sharing your found answer. :)